# How to split array of string those have comma and update as separate elements?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have mongo collection data like below:

```
{
  "tag1" : {
    "tag2" : [ 
      "test,test1",
      "sample"
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to **update collection** which has `"test,test1"` value in `tag2` array and update to separate elements `"test"`, `"test1"`, So the result should be like:

```
{
  "tag1" : {
    "tag2" : [ 
      "test",
      "test1",
      "sample"    
    ]
  }
}
```

MongoDB Version: 3.6

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop
- `$split` to split string by ','
- `$concatArrays` to concat current array and split string's array
- `$out` clone all updated documents in new collection

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addfields: {
      "tag1.tag2": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$tag1.tag2",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: ["$$value", { $split: ["$$this", ","] }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $out: "empty collection name" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NAG9U57-S4g)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. Actually, I want to update all records as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: I have updated answer you can check, use $out, i don't think there is other options in query mongodb 3.6, otherwise you have to do it manually by js code after retrieving records.

Comment: @VenugopalSeetharaman Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask